# Learning to use join between 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got two tables :

- STUDENT with the columns `ID, name, surname, class`
- SCORE with columns `Student ID, Score_date, Score, Discipline`

Display all students and their scores in Mathematics (whether or not they have a score):

```
SELECT Id, Name, Score
FROM STUDENT, SCORE
WHERE SCORE.Studentid = STUDENT.id 
  AND SCORE.Discipline = 'Mathematics';
```

How to do these queries using JOIN? I've tried to understand it on several sites, but it's still not clear (I'm new in SQL), can someone explain simply how it works?

Comment: These students are using archaic syntax.  And you should just forget that ever learned that commas are allowed in the `FROM` clause.  Use `JOIN`!

Comment: Why have you altered your request? Why have you removed two queries? Why does my answer not suffice? What else do you want to know?

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
FROM student, score WHERE student.id = score.studentid
```

is the syntax we used in the 1980s. In 1992 the SQL standard invented explicit joins:

```
FROM student INNER JOIN score ON student.id = score.studentid
```

If you are in a class where you are taught using the 1980s syntax, I'd say quit that class.

Anyway, both are joins. Inner joins at that. You join the tables `student` and `score` on the `sudentid` and only keep matches (i.e. if a student doesn't have any score row, you don't select that student).

Your second query doesn't contain a join, but a lookup with `NOT EXISTS`.

Your third query contains an inner join again. This, however, does not match the task where you are asked to also show students that are not in Mathematics. You'd need an outer join there:

```
SELECT st.id, st.name, sc.score AS math_score
FROM student st
LEFT OUTER JOIN score sc ON sc.studentid = st.id AND sc.discipline = 'Mathematics';
```